# Encryption And Decryption in Two different Java Programs

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to develop two java programs. One for encrypting plain text and another to decrypt that encrypted text.

Below is my code:

Encryption.java

```
public class Encryption {

    private static Cipher cipher = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String keyText = "9ofAGtArndXw9Ffu3lRTGWy9svXuUBl8";
        byte[] keyBytes = keyText.getBytes("UTF-8");

        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        System.out.println("Enter the plain text to be encrypted: ");
        String plainText = scan.nextLine();

        byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encrypt(plainTextByte, secretKey);

        String encryptedText = new String(encryptedBytes, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text After Encryption: " + encryptedText);
    }

    static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainTextByte, SecretKey secretKey) throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

}
```

> INPUT FOR Encryption.java : nonu AND
>   Ouput FROM Encryption.java : ??8???M?wFg(Ee

But when I enter the output from encryption.java in the decryption.java, it is giving me some error rather than giving me back the plain text.

Here is the Decryption.java code

```
public class Decryption {

    private static Cipher cipher = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String keyText = "9ofAGtArndXw9Ffu3lRTGWy9svXuUBl8";
        byte[] keyBytes = keyText.getBytes("UTF-8");

        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        System.out.println("Enter the encrypted text to be decrypted: ");
        String encryptedText = scan.nextLine();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt(encryptedBytes, secretKey);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Plain Text is: " + decryptedText);
    }

    static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes, SecretKey secretKey)
        throws Exception {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        return decryptedBytes;
    }

}
```

It is giving me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:936)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at encryption.Decryption.decrypt(Decryption.java:36)
    at encryption.Decryption.main(Decryption.java:27)
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least one problem, namely with this line:

```
String encryptedText = new String(encryptedBytes, "UTF-8");
```

The encrypted binary data will in general not be a valid UTF-8 encoding. This means you loose information when converting the bytes to a string.

Use base64 or some other encoding for binary data to convert the binary bytes to a string.

Comment: Although this answer is totally correct, I think the OP will be helped more if you provide the two-three lines of code outputting (and perhaps also converting back) the base64 string.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht I tend not to provide copy/paste ready solutions in order to leave room for some own research. This is an important skill that will help not only with one problem but also future ones. And frankly, I also would have to look up the details.